# Run a SQL Job From an asp.net mvc 4 web application

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-4, hangfire, sql-job

I need some help in figuring out how to start a SQL Server Agent Job from an asp.net mvc web application. The Job needs to be started on the click of a button. What is the right way of doing it?

I just installed hangfire and I'm trying to configure it but I'm stuck with the below code. Am i on the right track?

Any leads would be very helpful. Thanks.

```
public class MyController : Controller
{    
public void ExecJob(int Id)
    {
   BackgroundJob.Enqueue(() => UpdateDB(Id));  
    }

public void UpdateDB(Id)
    {
  //how to start the sql job
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by a "sql job".  Do you mean running a stored procedure or running an actual Sql Server Agent job?

Comment: I think your best bet is to write a stored procedure that will invoke the sql-server job.  Be warned, the "identity" of the account running the web site will have to be tested to see if it can start a sql-server job.  PS The faster you learn something like Quartz.Net, the better off you will be then trying to fudge everything through a sql-server-job.

Comment: @STLDeveloper: A sql server agent job

Answer (score 0):

You can use an SqlCommand (asp.net) like this:

```
var connection = new SqlConnection("<yourSqlConnectionString>");
var command = connection.CreateCommand();
command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
command.CommandText = "msdb.dbo.sp_start_job";
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@job_name", "<yourJobName>");

connection.Open();
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

(The code is not tested.)

Triggering an mssql-server-job can be achieved by using storedprocedure "sp_start_job".

Answer (score -1):

You can execute a stored procedure from the web application on click of a button

Stored procedure:

```
    CREATE PROCEDURE RunJob
       @JobName NVARCHAR(100)
    AS
    BEGIN
       -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
       -- interfering with SELECT statements.
       SET NOCOUNT ON;

       EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_start_job @JobName
    END
    GO
```

Create this stored procedure in your database and pass the job name as a parameter or you can hardcode the job name in the stored procedure to prevent accidental execution of other SQL jobs.